# No se puede crear una instancia de un control de usuario en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estoy teniendo problemas (e inestabilidad) con la interfaz gráfica en WPF, al tratar de incorporar controles me da un error de "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto". La llamada al namespace esta situada al inicio del documento.

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:CRM.Clientes"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Temporalmente, y solo en tiempo de codificación, si limpio la solución y vuelvo a compilar me permite incluir el control, sin embargo deja sobre el mismo un símbolo de admiración, no encuentro referencia de su significado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene una idea del por que pasa y el como solucionarlo?

Apendice:
1.- Código del control:

```
public partial class U_Empresa : UserControl
{
    public U_Empresa()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    U_Clientes padre;
    string idCliente = "";
    public int agregando = 0;

    public void setPadre(U_Clientes padreRecibido)
    {
        padre = padreRecibido;
        idCliente = padre.idCliente;

        DataTable datosCliente = DBConnection.getDatos("clientes", "idCliente", idCliente, " AND borrar=0");

        if (datosCliente.Rows.Count < 1) return;

        if (agregando != 1)
            lblNombre.Content = datosCliente.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString();
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el constructor del control que te esta mostrando el error.

Comment: listo, incluí el código completo

Comment: Muchas de las veces el icono de advertencia significa que has modificado la vista del control y que para reflejar los cambios correctamente en el editor, tienes que recompilar. No veo ningun error en lo que dices. Te inicia bien la aplicacion, verdad?

Comment: Así es, inicia, pero ese control no lo muestra, al detener la ejecución, vuelve el mensaje de error

Comment: No le hagas caso al VS. A mi tambien me ocurre y casi nunca puedo ver correctamente las vistas cuando las incluyo en otra vista. Si no te gusta el error, recompila, es lo unico que te puedo aconsejar.

Comment: Pues no seria problema, pero al ejecutar el programa esa vista no se muestra

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70578/discussion-between-einer-and-german-at).

Comment: En que visual studio te esta pasando esto? que contiene el xalm de U_Empresa. ? A mi cuando me pasa algo asi es solo porque las clases estan desactualizadas

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver el xaml de tu user control. Estos errores son normalmente errores del control,como estilos mal definidos y cosas asi.